# How to perform two actions simultaneoulsly while reading a file in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file -

Data1.csv

```
BusinessNeedParent,BusinessNeedChild,Identifier
a1,b1,45
a2,b2,60
a3,b3,56
```

Data2.csv

```
IndustryFoccusParent,IndustryFocusChild,Identifier
x1,y1,75
x2,y2,66
x3,y3,78
```

Data3.csv

```
AdvertiserName,BusinessNeedNumber,IndustryFocusNumber,State,City
worker,45,75,Calif,Los angeles
workplace,45,66,Calif,San Diego
platoon,60,66,Connec,Bridgeport
teracota,56,78,New York,Albany
worker,45,66,Calif,Los Angeles


AdvertiserName,BusinessNeedParent,BusinessNeedChild,IndustryFocusParent,IndustryFocusChild,State,City
worker,a1,b1,x1,y1,Calif,Los angeles
workplace,a1,b1,x2,y2,Calif,San Diego
platoon,a2,b2,x2,y2,Connec,Bridgeport
teracota,a3,b3,x3,y3,New York,Albany
worker,a2,b2,x2,y2,Calif,Los Angeles
```

I want to match the identifier and the BusinessNeedNumber and IndustryFocusNumber from Data1.csv and Data2.csv so as to  get the above output.

So far the code is like this -

```
record <- read.csv("Data3.csv",header=TRUE)
businessneedinformation <- read.csv("Data1.csv",header=TRUE)
industryFocusinformation <- read.csv("Data2.csv",header=TRUE)
```

I am using 'merge' at one at a time so as to get the output, I want to do it together

```
 m <- merge(Data1,Data3,by.x="Identifier",by.y="BusinessNeedNumber")
 n <- merge(Data2,Data3,by.x="Identifier",by.y="IndustryFocusNumber")
```

When I do it on a large data set it generates output of different length.
I want to perform both 'm' and 'n' together.  If  not merge what  are the other options available as  well? How to do it ? New to R,any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can only do two data frames with `merge` in base R. Try using the `join_all` function from the `plyr` package, or if you know sql, try the `sqldf` package. It occurs to me that I could actually show you an example. heh, long day

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
m <- merge(Data1,Data3,by.x="Identifier",by.y="BusinessNeedNumber", all.y=TRUE)
#use m instead of Data3
n <- merge(Data2,m,by.x="Identifier",by.y="IndustryFocusNumber", all.y=TRUE)
```